# SQL How can I group rows for every id and date without duplicates in names and arrange them

Tags: sql

I have got a problem and I have no idea how to solve it because I'm a beginner.

I have a table like this:

| id | date | time | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:00 | A |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:10 | A |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:20 | A |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:30 | B |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:40 | B |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:50 | C |
| 2 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 12:00 | A |
| 2 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 12:20 | B |

The desired result is as follows.
For each title I use only minimal time and after that I want to rank them for id and date:

| id | date | time | title | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:00 | A | 1 |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:30 | B | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 10:50 | C | 3 |
| 2 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 12:00 | A | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-03-03 | 2023-03-03 12:20 | B | 2 |

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you edit your question and tag the RDBMS you are using

Comment: Add a few other dates to the sample data, to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the window functions are supported by your database, you can use the function `row_number()` as follows:

```
select id, date, time, title, row_number() over (partition by id order by time) as rnk
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by id, title order by time) as rn
  from mytable
) as s
where rn = 1;
```

[Demo on mysql 8.0](https://dbfiddle.uk/8A7kOlCF)

Comment: Guys! Thanks for your help! Everything is great! I've solved it!

Comment: Perhaps use RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER? (In case of ties) https://dbfiddle.uk/4tbxGs6R

Comment: Or maybe `dense_rank()`  to assign a rank with no gaps in rank values

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired result, you need to first determine the minimum time for each title within each id and date group. Then, you can rank these titles based on their minimum time.

Here's a step-by-step solution using SQL:

Calculate the minimum time for each title within each id and date group.
Rank the titles based on their minimum time.

```
WITH RankedData AS (
    SELECT 
        id,
        date,
        title,
        MIN(time) AS min_time
    FROM 
        your_table_name
    GROUP BY 
        id, date, title
),
FinalRanking AS (
    SELECT 
        id,
        date,
        title,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY id, date ORDER BY min_time) AS rank
    FROM 
        RankedData
)
SELECT 
    id,
    date,
    time,
    title,
    rank
FROM 
    your_table_name t
JOIN 
    FinalRanking r ON t.id = r.id AND t.date = r.date AND t.title = r.title
ORDER BY 
    id, date, time;
```

Make sure to replace your_table_name with the actual name of your table. This SQL query will provide the desired output based on the sample data and requirements you've provided.